# How to design AWS infrastructure for my online course selling website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, architecture, amazon-cloudfront

I am designing an AWS architecture for hosting a website that sells online courses and merchandise products. For the purpose, I am planning to use the following architecture design:

- 1 VPC

  - 1 Application (RDS database + PHP web application)

    - Under Application, there can be 1 EC2 instance, 1 RDS database
    - S3 bucket

      - To store all static files, images, stylesheets, javascript files etc.
      - To upload all dynamic files, images, etc. (to be uploaded by users & website admin)
      - A CDN domain (e.g. cdn.mydomain.com) will be created to serve all files from S3 bucket.
  - 1 CloudFront (for content hosting & delivery)
  - AWS Router 53 (for domain & subdomain)

As per my knowledge and understanding, CloudFront should be used to deliver the content from S3 bucket that's why I am thinking of this.

**Question #1**: Should I create a VPC and encapsulate all AWS services/resources under it like S3, Application, RDS Database?

**Question #2**: Should CloudFront be used for the purpose?

**Question #3**: Is there any better approach for achieving this?

**Note**: *Please note that I am trying to utilize the resources under Free Tier as much as possible to avoid cost as this is an initial phase of the website and I will be selling my courses through this as of now. And, there will be videos for each session/lecture where each video can be of 2GB or more in size and for 1 course there can be 40-50 videos that students can access only after making a purchase.*
*Also, I would love to know if I should add anything that I missed.*

Happy to hear experts' advise/suggestions on this.

Comment: In addition to this, I will be using Elastic Beanstalk which I find quite useful for easy configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question #1: Should I create a VPC and encapsulate all AWS services/resources under it like S3, Application, RDS Database?**

If you use Elastic Beanstalk, you shouldn't have to worry too much about this, since it is a PaaS service (platform-as-a-service) that would take care of it for you. Be careful about the free tier limits and platform locking.

**Question #2: Should CloudFront be used for the purpose?**

You don't need CloudFront to serve your S3 content. It will be too pricey for what you want to achieve. Every object in your S3 bucket has a unique URL that you can use directly. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327425/when-to-use-amazon-cloudfront-or-s3

- S3 are not VPC bound by default. You can decide to do it for security reasons but it's optional.

**Question #3: Is there any better approach for achieving this?**

There are many different approaches available. It depends on your requirements : number of users, proximity of users, High Availability requirements, size of the content served, etc. You can read about [System Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_design) to get more information about this.